# How do I render a partial from a string?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I might be doing something here that's a bit of a hack, but I'm trying to separate out my css into it's own partial, and retain the ability to resolve the model.  I have the following css and cshtml

document-colours.css

```
:root {
    --key-primary: @Model.PrimaryColour;
}
```

index.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans' rel='stylesheet' />
    
    @await Html.InlineStyle("document-colours")
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Definition of `Html.InlineStyle`

```
public static async Task<IHtmlContent> InlineStyle(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string styleSheetName)
{
    var styling = await File.ReadAllTextAsync($"wwwroot/css/{styleSheetName}.css");
    return htmlHelper.Raw($"<style>{styling}</style>");
}
```

So this half works, the html returned when I request the Index view is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans' rel='stylesheet' />
    
    <style>
    :root {
        --key-primary: @Model.PrimaryColour;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The model contains a valid value for Primary colour.

I could convert my css to views, but this would be time consuming so I'm wondering if it's possible to have `InlineStyle` render the string before returning it?  I only seem to be able to render views that are available at compile time.

Edit: just to make it clear, this is a simplified example, in reality I have many larger css files that are used by multiple razor pages.  My goal here is to make my css parameterizable whilst also allowing it to be reuseable.

Comment: Why not just use partial view for this?

Comment: This is an application I'm converting from asp.net to asp.net core, and as per my post, I have a lot of code that's already formatted as css.  In asp.net the rendering engine worked differently so the above code worked, but now it fails because it doesn't rerender the view after retrieving the css.  I could convert the css to a view, but it's non trivial given I'd have a lot of modifications to make

Answer (score 0):

Updating your `InlineStyle` HTML Helper to execute the `PartialAsync` HTML Helper, along with a colors model, can return your solution back to the way it used to work.

```
@await Html.InlineStyle("document-colours", Model.Colors)
```

**`InlineStyle` HTML Helper**

```
// Extend parameters to include a colors model
public static async Task<IHtmlContent> InlineStyle(
    this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string styleSheetName, CssColors colors)
{
    // Execute the built-in 'PartialAsync' HTML Helper with model
    string styleSheetPath = $"/wwwroot/css/{styleSheetName}.css";
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent HtmlContent =
        await htmlHelper.PartialAsync(styleSheetPath, colors);

    // Write HTML content to a string
    System.IO.StringWriter writer = new();
    HtmlContent.WriteTo(writer, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
    string styling = writer.ToString();

    return htmlHelper.Raw($"<style>{styling}</style>");
}
```

**`PartialAsync` HTML Helper**

The built-in `PartialAsync` HTML Helper handles a `.css` file, surprisingly, although it makes some sense that the helper loads the content of a file, looks for any Razor syntax to execute, and then returns a stream of text without modifying any of non-Razor syntax text content.

Here's a [link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/HtmlHelper.cs) to the open source class file. The `PartialAsync` method:

```
public async Task<IHtmlContent> PartialAsync(
    string partialViewName,
    object model,
    ViewDataDictionary viewData)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(partialViewName);

    var viewBuffer = new ViewBuffer(_bufferScope, partialViewName, ViewBuffer.PartialViewPageSize);
    using (var writer = new ViewBufferTextWriter(viewBuffer, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        await RenderPartialCoreAsync(partialViewName, model, viewData, writer);
        return viewBuffer;
    }
}
```

**IntelliSense and a Partial View**

Unlike adding the colors model to a `.css` file, using a Razor partial view, however, provides the benefits of IntelliSense when adding colors from a model; and verifying color properties in the model are valid at design/compile time.

_CssRootPartial.cshtml

```
@model CssColors

:root {
    --key-primary: @Model.PrimaryColour;
    --key-secondary: @Model.SecondaryColour;
}
```

**Full solution**

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@using WebApplication1.Helpers
@model WebApplication1.Pages.Index
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans' rel='stylesheet' />

    <style>
        /* @await Html.PartialAsync("/Pages/Partials/_Colors.cshtml", Model.Colors) */
        /* @await Html.PartialAsync("/wwwroot/css/document-colours.css", Model.Colors) */
    </style>
    @await Html.InlineStyle("document-colours", Model.Colors)
    <style>
        .box {
            width: 2rem;
            height: 2rem;
        }
    
        .box.red {
            border: 1px solid var(--key-primary);
        }

        .box.blue {
            border: 1px solid var(--key-secondary);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public CssColors Colors = new();
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }

    public class CssColors
    {
        public string PrimaryColour { get; set; } = "#ff0000"; // red
        public string SecondaryColour { get; set; } = "#0000ff"; // blue
    }
}
```

InlineStyle.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using WebApplication1.Pages;

namespace WebApplication1.Helpers
{
    public static class HTMLHelpers
    {
    // Extend parameters to include a colors model
    public static async Task<IHtmlContent> InlineStyle(
        this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string styleSheetName, CssColors colors)
    {
        // Execute the built-in 'PartialAsync' HTML Helper with model
        string styleSheetPath = $"/wwwroot/css/{styleSheetName}.css";
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent HtmlContent =
            await htmlHelper.PartialAsync(styleSheetPath, colors);

        // Write HTML content to a string
        System.IO.StringWriter writer = new();
        HtmlContent.WriteTo(writer, System.Text.Encodings.Web.HtmlEncoder.Default);
        string styling = writer.ToString();

        return htmlHelper.Raw($"<style>{styling}</style>");
    }

        // Use 'string.Replace()' method
        public static async Task<IHtmlContent> InlineStyle_With_Model(
            this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string styleSheetName, CssColors colors)
        {
            string styling = await File.ReadAllTextAsync($"wwwroot/css/{styleSheetName}.css");
            styling = styling.Replace("primaryColour", colors.PrimaryColour);
            return htmlHelper.Raw($"<style>{styling}</style>");
        }

        // Original 'InlineStyle' HTML Helper
        public static async Task<IHtmlContent> InlineStyle_Orig(
            this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string styleSheetName)
        {
            var styling = await File.ReadAllTextAsync($"wwwroot/css/{styleSheetName}.css");
            return htmlHelper.Raw($"<style>{styling}</style>");
        }
    }
}
```

document-colors.css

```
:root {
    --key-primary: @Model.PrimaryColour;
    --key-secondary: @Model.SecondaryColour;
}
```

Output:

[image]

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        /* 
    :root {
        --key-primary: #ff0000;
        --key-secondary: #0000ff;
    }
 */
        /* :root {
    --key-primary: #ff0000;
    --key-secondary: #0000ff;
}
 */
    </style>
    <style>:root {
    --key-primary: #ff0000;
    --key-secondary: #0000ff;
}
</style>
    <style>
        .box {
            width: 2rem;
            height: 2rem;
        }
    
        .box.red {
            border: 1px solid var(--key-primary);
        }

        .box.blue {
            border: 1px solid var(--key-secondary);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>
</body>
</html>
```